# pagination in jekyll not working

Tags: github, pagination, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I'm trying to add pagination in my [Jekyll based project](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/).

So far, I have followed the below steps:

- [Pagination in jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/)
- Followed [Eric](http://www.ericlagergren.com/blog/jekyll-pagination/) but no avail

I have set up [_config.yml](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml) like this:

```
#Show 5 posts each page 
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/index/page:num/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your posts printing loop you're using :

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
```

But, you must use :

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
```